# Custom Containers In Visual Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I want to create a custom root container like **section** in visual composer.

And i was able to do with the below code

```
vc_map(array(
    'is_container' => true,
    'show_settings_on_create' => false, 
    'class' => 'vc_main-sortable-element',
    'description' => 'Group multiple rows in section.',
    'name' => __( 'Master Section', 'booss' ),
    'base' => 'booss_master_section',
    "js_view" => 'VcMasterSection',
))
```

But when add this its getting added with

```
[vc_row][vc_column][booss_master_section][/booss_master_section][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

i need the output to be like `[booss_master_section][/booss_master_section]`

I tried changing the value of **js_view** to `VcSectionView` | `VcRowView`

None of them works.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for Is the option `'is_container' => true,`